# What does 'had' mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I knew I had to get this award

This means *this award had to be mine* (it was *bound to happen*)...

Or does it mean *I needed to get this award*?

Answer (score 2):

It means 'I knew that I wanted this award so much that I would experience a lot of pain if I did not win it'.  A similar expression would be 'I have to have her'.  That means: 'I want her so much that if I don't have her, then I will experience a lot of pain.'

Comment: Doesn't it mean this award had to be mine. It was bound to happen?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  But I see why you think that.  When someone says: 'the bridge was so decayed that it had to fall down', in that context 'had' means 'bound to happen'.

Comment: Using 'had' in those contexts is not very good English and is discouraged because it's so vague.